# Shopware 6 Create link of plugin settings in side navigation

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm working on a Shopware 6 plugin and I would like to add a link to the plugin settings in the main navigation.

[image]
This Item should navigate to

[image]

I have tried the following code:

```json
VUEJS Module

...

navigation: [{
{
  id: 'm28.scg.settings',
  label: 'scg.settings.title',
  color: '#ff3d58',
  path: 'sw.extension.module',
  params: {
    moduleName: 'MindsShoppingCartGoals'
  },
  icon: 'default-device-server',
  parent: 'm28.scg',
  position: 0
}]

...
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [original route](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/086770f0a78af332b9728f60c103e0233ce8f8c0/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-extension/index.js#L136) for reference. This should do it:

```js
{
    // ...
    
    navigation: [{
        id: 'm28.scg.settings',
        label: 'scg.settings.title',
        color: '#ff3d58',
        path: 'sw.extension.config',
        params: {
            namespace: 'MindsShoppingCartGoals'
        },
        icon: 'default-device-server',
        parent: 'm28.scg',
        position: 0
    }]
}
```